# ie7 has dedicated css but it also loads the non dedicated one

Tags: internet-explorer-7

hope sombody can enlighten me here,

i am writing a joomla template.
ie7 has a seperate css using:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ;?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ;?>/css/template_ie7.css" type="text/css" />  
<![endif]-->
```

but is also loads the non ie7 css and accepts its styles, so nothing get fixed....

does anybody know what to do?

thanks,
Jonatahn

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional css loading this way is not (at least for me) the best way to handle this situation.

As you are writing a template you can acces to the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable in order to determine if the iExplorer (or any other) css is needed and then use php to filter it's load

```
<?php
if(stripos ( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE 7.0") > 0 ){
    /* LOAD IE7 CSS here */
}else{
    /* LOAD normal CSS here */
}
?>
```

This way you can load the IE7 css ONLY.